# Why does location service turn itself off?

Tags: ios, geolocation

I have an iOS application that has been marked as needing background service (Location Updates). When the app is in the foreground, I see the location arrow in the top status bar. However if I double-click the home button to send my app to background, the location service turns itself off and my app no longer receives location updates.

The same happens with Google Maps and Apple Maps apps.

I am running iOS 7 on iPhone 4S.

How do I ensure that my app receives location updates when running in the background?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is new to iOS7 but the "Background App Refresh" setting under

Settings -> General -> Background App Refresh

needs to be on for the specific application to receive background location updates.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is new to iOS 7.